# How to find what the next word separated by underscore is

Tags: python, regex

I have a Python application that uploads a specific file and finds the correct location path to it.

The first path has two possibilities: **path1** or **path2**

The second path has about 4-5 possibilities. All the files uploaded will be named is similar to this:

```
GE_1234_path1_possib1_655_ygiu_qis
```

To find which path is written, I wrote this `if-else` statement:

```
path1 = re.search(r'path1', self.fileList[0])
path2 = re.search(r'path2', self.fileList[0])
        if path1:
            radioButton = 2

        if path2:
            radioButton = 1
```

I know I can apply the same if else statement to the 5 possibilities. However I prefer to read what is written exactly after **path1**. Is there a way with regex to skip the underscore after path and read what the possibility is?

In this example, I'm looking for something that would output **possib1**

I tried:

```
print re.findall(r'path1\w', self.fileList[0])
```

but that just prints `path1_`

Comment: Have a look at [this demo](https://ideone.com/Ct0XzP) - is it what you are looking for?

Comment: @stribizhev yes sir that is exactly what I am looking for

Comment: Posted, please check. Let me know if you need more clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following regex :

```
print re.findall(r'path1_([^_]+)', self.fileList[0])
```

`([^_]+)` is a negated character class within a capture group which will match anything except `_` after `path1_`.

See demo https://regex101.com/r/wM4iI6/1

Answer (score 1):

Use capturing group to capture the alphanumeric characters which exists next to `path1`.

```
print re.findall(r'path1\w([A-Za-z\d]+)', self.fileList[0])
```

or

```
>>> s = 'GE_1234_path1_possib1_655_ygiu_qis'
>>> spl = s.split('_')
>>> for i,j in enumerate(spl):
    if 'path1' in j:
        print(spl[i+1])


possib1
>>>
```

Comment: why is it printing it in an array ['possib1'] instead of a string ? is that because we are using findall ?

Comment: yap, use `re.search` instead. `print re.search(r'path1\w([A-Za-z\d]+)', self.fileList[0]).group(1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'path\d+_([^_]+)')
test_str = ur"GE_1234_path1_possib1_655_ygiu_qis"
match = p.search(test_str)
if match:
    print match.group(1)
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/Ct0XzP)

The regex - `path\d+_([^_]+)` - matches `path`, then a digit(s) and an underscore, then it matches and captures into Group 1 one or more characters other than `_`. And then we access that group 1 if a match is found.